# How do you load 3 floats using neon intrinsics

Tags: arm, neon, intrinsics

I'm trying to convert this neon code to intrinsics:

```
vld1.32                {d0}, [%[pInVertex1]]
flds                   s2, [%[pInVertex1], #8]
```

This loads 3 32-bit floats from the variable pInVertex1 into the d0 and d1 registers.
I can't find any equivalent version for instrinsics. There is vld1q_f32, but that only works for 4 floats. Anyone know of a efficient way of doing this (I mean without extra copying)?

Comment: Is it possible to tweak the register usage such that it could work with a one-lane `vld3`, i.e. `s0`, `s2`, `s4` rather than `s0`, `s1`, `s2`? (although I'm not sure offhand what that would look like in intrinsics.) Otherwise, it may be worth considering that loading 4 elements with a single `vld1` and ignoring one of them will will be no less efficient than two separate instructions (and possibly moreso), provided that a) it's OK to trash `s3` and b) you lay out the data such that it's never problematic to read past the end.

Comment: Maybe, I could do it, but it would only work for loading values. When I write out the 3 values into the array I have the same problem. If I write 4 values, then I am overriding data from a different vertex.

Answer (score 0):

The only instruction that writes only 3 32-bit floats in Aarch32 is a multiple-load instruction:

```
r0 holds the address of the structure
FLDMIAS r0, {s0-s2}
```

This can be used either in VFP or Neon code.

I do not know about the corresponding intrinsic.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful to know. So, it's the intrinsic version of FLDMIAS that I need.

Answer (score 0):

In [DirectXMath](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/) I implemented the ARM-NEON version of `XMLoadFloat3` as:

```
float32x2_t x = vld1_f32( reinterpret_cast<const float*>(pSource) );
float32x2_t zero = vdup_n_f32(0);
float32x2_t y = vld1_lane_f32( reinterpret_cast<const float*>(pSource)+2, zero, 0 );
return vcombine_f32( x, y );
```